# Getting content list to FragmentAdapter (viewpager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have question list in my database. Questions appears on my page one by one with prev/next buttons.
I want to add viewpager for swiping between questions. But getting content to FragmentAdapter confused me.

FragmentAdapter:

```
class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", };

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you get content from database, you dont need to use string content;

You need to use fragments. Create fragment with a textview then populate it for every next position. Then update your content with `position`

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {  

public static TestFragment newInstance(int index ) {

         TestFragment TestFragment = new TestFragment();
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();         
         bundle.putInt("index", index);
         TestFragment.setArguments(bundle);
         return TestFragment;
     }

 @Override  
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {              
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);  
          text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourtext);  
text.setText("your position: " + getArguments().getInt("index")) // where you get index from your newinstance
}
}
```